# Game intro page. Using JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to make an intro page for a game I am working on for class. I managed to display an image in JFrames but I have no idea how to make the buttons work. Heres the code:

```
package nba_shootout_vol_two;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Image;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Button;

public class Runner{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f=new JFrame("NBA Shootout Vol.2");

    try{
        f.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("img/title.jpg")))));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Image doesn't exitst");
    }
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setSize(1280,720);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

So will make this pop up:

[image]

How to make the buttons clickable and be able to actually do stuff?

Comment: See the [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). Please go through the entire [tutorial on making a GUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) before asking questions. This is basic stuff & it's all set out, with examples.

Comment: As an aside, it seems the `img/title.jpg` is all that is being added to the frame, implying that `Play Game` and `Instructions` are all part of that same image. That complicates things. I suggest you first learn how to start the game with plain buttons, and revisit the more complicated task of carving up an image for use as button icons later.

Answer (score -1):

It appears to me you are reinventing the buttons, whats a good idea I think. So, how can you check if they are clicked :

- You need a MouseListener
- You need a function that checks if you are on a rect

Example EventHandler:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class EventHandler implements MouseListener {
    public JFrame pane;
    public int mouse_x;
    public int mouse_y;
    public int[] mouse=new int[5];
    @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {
         switch (m.getButton()) {
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON1) :
                 mouse[2]=1;
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON2) :
                 mouse[3]=1;
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON3) :
                 mouse[4]=1;

         }
     }
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
         switch (m.getButton()) {
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON1) :
                 mouse[2]=2;
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON2) :
                 mouse[3]=2;
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON3) :
                 mouse[4]=2;
         }
     }
     @Override
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {
         switch (m.getButton()) {
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON1) :
                 mouse[2]=3;
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON2) :
                 mouse[3]=3;
             case (MouseEvent.BUTTON3) :
                 mouse[4]=3;
         }
     }
     @Override
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m) {
     }
     @Override
     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m) {
     }
     public void getMouse() {
         Component[] rel;
         rel = pane.getComponents();
         mouse_x=mouse[0]=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-rel[0].getLocationOnScreen().x;
         mouse_y=mouse[1]=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-rel[0].getLocationOnScreen().y;
     }
     public void updateMouse() {
         for (int i=0; i < mouse.length; i++) {
              mouse[i]=0;
         }
     }
     public void work() {
         getMouse();
         pane.requestFocus();
     }
     public void reset() {
         updateMouse();
     }
    public EventHandler(Frame plane) {
        this.pane=plane;
        pane.requestFocus();
        pane.addMouseListener(this);
    }
}
```

- use it like the following :

  - init : `EventHandler events=new EventHandler(f);`
  - you are supposed to have a game loop :
  - note : the int[] mouse is : x, y, left button, middle button, right button

The game with loop and rect_collide:

```
package nba_shootout_vol_two;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Image;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Button;

public class Runner{
public static EventHandler events;
public static boolean rect_collide(int bx, int by, int bw, int bh) {
     return (events.mouse_x > bx && events.mouse_x < bx+bw && events.mouse_y > by && events.mouse_y < by+bh);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f=new JFrame("NBA Shootout Vol.2");

    try{
        f.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("img/title.jpg")))));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Image doesn't exitst");
    }
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setSize(1280,720);
    f.setVisible(true);
    events=new EventHandler(f);
    while (true) { //Game loop
        events.work();
        if (events.mouse[2]) { //Left mouse button down
            if (rect_collide(0,0,20,20)) { //Collision with button at x=0 y=0 w=20 h=20
                //Do your stuff
            }
        }
        f.repaint(); //Update the display since you are going to have changements after pressing the button
        events.reset();
    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps you. If you are having any questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: *"It appears to me you are reinventing the buttons, whats a good idea I think."* It ranks right up there with 'reinventing the wheel'.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : I know.